# Shift-Invariant Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

One way to define a *shift-invariant space* is
$$V(\phi,\mathbb{Z}):=\left\{\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}c_j\phi(\cdot-j):(c_j)\in\ell_2\right\},$$
where convergence of the series is taken to be in $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.  Under appropriate conditions on $\phi$, this is a closed subspace of $L_2(\mathbb{R})$.

On the other hand, let $$W(\phi,\mathbb{Z}):=\overline{span}^{L_2(\mathbb{R})}\left\{\phi(\cdot-j):j\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}.$$ 
Is $W(\phi,\mathbb{Z})=V(\phi,\mathbb{Z})$? (i.e. are these definitions equivalent?) And does the same reasoning apply for subspaces of $L_p$ for $p\neq2$?